# Container fills the screen even when I specify `width` and `height`

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, flutter-container

I am working on a flutter project, and I would like to display a `Container` inside another one with specific sizes. However, when I specify the size of the `Container`s, it doesn't take it into consideration.

Here is a code sample:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyWidget());
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200.0,
      height: 200.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Container(
        width: 20.0,
        height: 20.0,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is what I get, I cannot see the blue `Container`.

[image]

What is happening, and what should I do?

Comment: add `alignment: Alignment.center,` to parent container

Comment: Thanks! It solved the issue. Do you know the reason why it doesn't work when there is no alignment specified?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I mentioned in comment you need to specify where the second box would be

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 200.0,
      height: 200.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        width: 20.0,
        height: 20.0,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify where the second box would be

```
   Container(
        width: 200.0,
        height: 200.0,
        color: Colors.orange,
        alignment: Alignment.center, // where to position the child
        child: Container(
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, what happens here is that you're directly passing the `Container` as the root widget. So, the container has to occupy the entire screen as it doesn't know what else to show in the background. So, you will see that it occupies the entires screen. With respect to the red-colored container, it seems that it also follows the same property as its parent. So, it fills the entire screen. Unless, we specify the `alignment` property.

I added the alignment property to the parent as well. Yet, it still occupies the entire screen.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyWidget());
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 40.0,
      height: 40.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 20.0,
        height: 20.0,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```